# What is an efficient method to map errors(exceptions) occuring in a J2EE website with suitable error messages?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web, exception

I am developing a J2EE website for a mini project, and I’m puzzled about exception handling. I have defined several custom exception classes, and they’re thrown from several parts of the website, and they are captured in a custom exception handler. But, i am yet to find a good way to map the occurred Exception to an error message.

To put it simply, if an exception occurs somewhere, I have a global exception handler which captures the thrown exception ( i won't swallow it within a local catch block ), but i need an efficient mechanism by which i should be able to convert it into a suitable error message to be displayed to the end users.

Also, the custom exceptions have a tree hierarchy , which means the top of the tree will have general exceptions and the leaves of the tree would have exceptions defined for a very specific purpose.

The tree would be like

```
CustomException

    Type1Exception
        Type11Exception
        Type12Exception
            Type121Exception
            Type122Exception
        Type13Exception

    Type2Exception
        Type21Exception
            Type211Exception
        Type22Exception

    Type3Exception
        Type31Exception
        Type32Exception
        Type33Exception

    Type4Exception
        Type41Exception
            Type411Exception
                Type4111Exception
                Type4112Exception
            Type421Exception
                Type4211Exception
        Type42Exception
```

Each exception branch would represent exceptions occurring in specific part of the website.  The tree will grow more in future, if more features are added to the website What is the best practice to map the bunch of exceptions to error messages ?

And, is using **instanceOf** operator and **isInstance()** method , to check the type of exception, a good practice (in aspects of performance ,scalability and code standards) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each exception branch would represent exceptions occurring in specific
>   part of the website.

But what if the exception happens in a common component shared by different parts of the website?

Exceptions already tell you where they happened (that's what the stacktrace is for), you don't need to put it in the name. The name is for the reason of the exception (such as `IllegalArgumentException` or `EOFException`.

Your design is poor in many ways. You should handle exceptions where you can, either locally with a specific error message (if let's say a user wants to pick a username that's already taken) or globally with a general error message.

Edit:
There are thousands of potential error situations in an application. You can divide them into categories based on what you can do to them. Let's say you try to insert a duplicate username into the database, and an exception is thrown. You catch this and tell the user to choose a different username.

That's the least exceptional case, you might even bypass this by checking if the username exists, instead of relying on an exception.

Then you have a bit more exceptional, let's say you can't connect to the database at all. You don't know why, but you're still prepared, you tell the user that something is wrong with the database, and please try again.

Then you have the most exceptional. You're not prepared for it, you don't have a catch clause for it, it flies up to the global exception handler. All you can do is show the user a generic error message that "Something went wrong", log the error, and notify the maintenance team.

Now the way to design exceptions is based on how much information you know about what happened. You might have a `DatabaseException` class for all DB related errors, and a `DuplicateUserException` that extends it to provide more detail. Also note that a `DuplicateUserException` would never propagate up to a global exception handler. You'd handle it right there, showing the user the screen with the error message. The error message which you'd get from a resource bundle not with the name of the exception, but a general key, such as "exception.user.duplicate".

I think your basic mistake is thinking that you can create a single place responsible for exception handling, just based on the exception type. I suggest that you let that idea go. The global handler should only handle (mainly log) the exception when nobody else will.

Comment: Custom exceptions are mostly wrappers of the common exceptions that occur in Java. They provide much clearer information about the nature of the exception (even for non-developers) , since I'll be passing some other parameters to the exception (username, page URL and other session specific stuffs) which I'll log from the error handler. The primary goal of custom exceptions is to ensure that no exception defined in Java will be thrown during execution. And, as for exceptions occuring in a common component, there'll be a bunch of common exceptions which can be used for those sections.

Comment: @Barath I know what custom exceptions are for. They're still used to specify a type of an exception, not a location. As you said yourself, you'll be passing username, URL, etc. as parameters to the exception. It would be foolish to make the exception tree match the structure of your application.

Comment: So, are you saying that it's better to not form a tree structure, but just include all exceptions under a single package ?

And anyway, the point of the question is the mapping of exceptions to error messages. Should i do soemthing like, put **exception class's name** and corresponding error message as a key-pair value in a resource bundle ? Or, is there a better approach ?

And, is using instanceOf and isInstance() efficient and good practice ?

Comment: If you're making a small Java EE application, I'd say anything over 5-7 custom exceptions means that you don't really understand what you're doing. As for packages for the exceptions, maybe 2, even one would suffice for a small app. You don't want to map an exception directly to an error message either, since an exception can correspond to several different messages. Anyway I'd recommend that you don't try to be too clever here, your initial design was already so crazy that you clearly aren't experienced with designing an application wide exception scheme.

Comment: I'm not trying to be clever. But, defining a custom exception class for each error that may occur in the project is one of the requirements. That's why I'm defining an exception scheme this big. And, if one exception can correspond to several error messages, do i use a flag of some sort to denote the subtype ?